# danger in using id property for Mongoose models?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Database design decision making here and there's no other way to do this but poll the experts on SO.

We are using the Mongoose ODM with Node.js Express. MongoDB uses _id as the default property on models which hold ObjectIDs unique to each document.

We are using an auto-incrementer which gives integer ids to each model. We want to call this field 'id' which will complement the '_id' field.

My concern is that there is a small risk that using an 'id' field will cause problems. Does anyone have experience positive or negative with using 'id' for integer ids on all their Mongoose models?

Comment: I've used autoincrementers for mongoose as well. Typically, we just get specific and give it it's own extra id field, e.g. `Article` has `articleId: Number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, be very careful. Mongoose by default adds a virtual property called `"id"` to your model. This virtual property returns the cast to String of the _id property.

If you really want to add a real property `"id"` to your model your must turn off this automatic virtual using the option: `{id: false}` in your `new Schema()` calls:

```
new Schema({name: String, id: int}, {id: false})
```

Be aware that even if this possible you will confuse every developer who knows mongoose when he reads your code by doing this.

Maybe better call your property differently.

Or when you create this incrementing id anyway as your primary key maybe you can assign it to _id directly because then there is probably no need to generate an additional ObjectId anyway... and the id property will then automatically return your integer as a String.